# Fortran get_environment_variable intrinsic returns nothing

Tags: fortran, environment-variables, gfortran, intrinsics

I know that Fortran 2003 contains the intrinsic subroutine get_environment_variable, but I can't get it to return the variable I want. Here is a test program:

```
program main
  implicit none
  character(len=10) :: time

  call get_environment_variable("t", time)
  write(6,*) time
end program main
```

I then set t=2010010100 (or something) in the shell, compile and run, and the only thing written is a blank line. I don't understand: I'm using gfortran with the flag -std=f2003, this should be simple, what's being hung up? I suspect it's quite simple and the answer will expose my ignorance....but thank you anyways!

Comment: Works for me. In what environment are you running?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I'm on Windows and it works for me in a cmd shell, but if I try it in msys bash, I can't get it to work either. Have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you need to export the environment variable, otherwise it won't be passed to the program.

PS you do this using the "export" command, e.g.

```
export t=2010010100
```

Comment: PS you do this using the "export" command, e.g. export t=2010010100

Comment: You can edit your answer using the grey "edit" link below it.